# How to calculate the path to a child node in a tree?

Tags: javascript

I have a tree like this:

```
var tree = [
  {
    type: "folder",
    children: [
      {
        type: "folder",
        children: [
          {
            type: "document",
            id: 1,
            children: []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    type: "folder",
    children: []
  }
];
```

The leafs of this tree always have an empty `children` array.

I need to construct a function which will return the path of indices to the node which satisfies the given condition. The function would be called like this:

```
getPathToNode(tree, function (node) {
  return node.type === "document" && node.id === 1;
})
```

and would return the following:

```
[0, 0, 0]
```

which describes the path to that node:

```
tree[0].children[0].children[0]
```

This recursive function is what I got so far:

```
function getPathToNode(tree, fn) {
  return tree.reduce(function (path, node, i) {
    if (fn(node)) {
      return path.concat(i);
    }
    if (node.children.length > 0) {
      const pathToNode = getPathToNode(node.children, fn);
      return pathToNode.length > 0 ? path.concat(i, pathToNode) : [];
    }
    return [];
  }, []);
}
```

I think the function needs to build a path while traversing, then, if it reaches a leaf without finding the node, delete only the part of that path which belonged to the branch where the node wasn't found, then continue with other branches.

Comment: Have you tried learning/using recursion?

Comment: I edited my question to include what I've tried so far. Yes, this is definitely a job for recursion, which I usually managed with, but this task is much harder for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This proposal uses [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), because of a possible early exit of the iteration.

Then you could use a variable for level and the wanted indices.

```js
function getPathToNode(node, fn) {
    var path = [];
    return node.some(function iter(level) {
        return function (a, i) {
            path.length = level;
            path[level] = i;
            return fn(a) || a.children.some(iter(level + 1));
        };
    }(0)) && path;
}

var tree = [{ type: "folder", children: [{ type: "folder", children: [{ type: "document", id: 1, children: [] }] }] }, { type: "folder", children: [] }],
    result = getPathToNode(tree, function (node) {
        return node.type === "document" && node.id === 1;
    });

console.log(result);
```

A different version with a temporary array instead of a level.

```js
function getPathToNode(node, fn) {
    var path = [];
    return node.some(function iter(p) {
        return function (a, i) {
            if (fn(a)) {
                path = p.concat(i);
                return true;
            }
            return a.children.some(iter(p.concat(i)));
        };
    }([])) && path;
}

var tree = [{ type: "folder", children: [{ type: "folder", children: [{ type: "document", id: 1, children: [] }] }] }, { type: "folder", children: [] }],
    result = getPathToNode(tree, function (node) {
        return node.type === "document" && node.id === 1;
    });

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @silvenon, too much?

Comment: No, very little, that's why it's impressive. :)